# Application could not be Installed on this phone

Tags: android

I have my own Android Application, I named it "SMS App" and I want to install it at my Android Phone, but every time I install this application in phone there is a message that pop up:

> Application not Installed. SMS App could not be Installed on this
>   phone.

Anyone who encountered this and solved this kind of problems?

Comment: You would have to provide some logcat logs to help you. More about logcat here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html

Comment: to view logs you need to open ddms  from 'android-sdk\tools\ddms.bat'. Most probably it shld be a problem with sdk version as Nik said.

Comment: @Ankit Jain  I'm sorry but I'm a newbie in Android, theres a lot of Questions from me will be discuss, first of all after I opened ddms from tools of SDK I don't know how to use it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to check:

- Minumum SDK version
- If it is an unsigned version, it WILL NOT overwrite a signed version installed currently on your phone.  Uninstall current version, or sign your test .apk and try again.
- Check under Settings > applications > install from unknown sources.  Must be checked to install things not from market

Comment: what do you mean? is it Settings from Android Phone?

Comment: Thanks, I followed your Instruction and now I can now Install my desired application in Android Phone.. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your phone android version and you develop "SMS App" APK version your phone version is lower than you develop "SMS App" apk so not installed.