# Android Application Not Installing (APK)

Tags: java, android, installation, emulation, apk

I tried porting one of my old simple Java apps to Android and exporting as an APK.  It installs and runs fine on the Emulator, but when I attempt to install it on a real Android phone, it just says "Application not installed"

I am using the ADT for Eclipse plugin to export the APK.

I assume the issue must be with the manifest since the program won't even install nor launch (either that or the export process itself).  I haven't tried doing it from the command line yet.... I've been avoiding it.  I will try that if no one can find any problems with my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="bg.java.mobile"
  android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Heat Index" android:logo="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name="AppLauncher"
         android:label="@string/app_name" android:multiprocess="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:screenOrientation="user">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027964/application-could-not-be-installed-on-this-phone, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/application-not-installed-error-on-android or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383470/application-not-installed?

Comment: Yes but this had my own specific manifest...

Comment: I don't see anything out of the ordinary in your manifest, so the error cause is most likely one of the "common mistakes". Did you do the checks described in the first post I mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled 'unknown sources' on your phone? (Settings->Applications) Else you can't install apk files.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqr5G.png